# Azure Traffic Manager availability

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

As per the [Traffic Manager FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs) in the unlikely event of an outage of an entire Azure region, Traffic Manager is expected to continue to function normally.

Can someone please confirm if during an Azure worldwide outage, Azure Traffic Manager is expected to function normally or not?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic manager is not a regional deployment. It is a service which spans across data centers. In case of any regional outages, your Traffic manager still continues to work but the endpoint which you have added might fail as it is a regional deployment.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

During an Azure worldwide outage, Azure Traffic Manager will also be affected and **will not function normally**.

**Explanation:**

In the [Non-regional services (always-available services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/availability-zones-service-support#an-icon-that-signifies-this-service-is-non-regional-non-regional-services-always-available-services) list you can see `'Azure Traffic Manager'`.

**Always-available services:** Always available across all Azure geographies and are resilient to **zone-wide** outages and **region-wide** outages.

It means, in the case of zone-wide or region-wide outages Azure Traffic Manager functions normally but during world-wide outage it will not.